# How a discord bot can join a voice channel in discord rewrite?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make my discord bot to connect to the voice channel I am when I type `!join`.
i have tried to do it with the following code but i got this error:
`bot: BotInstance of 'Bot' has no 'voice_client_int' memberpylint(no-member)`

i found that my code is not compatible with the rewrite discord version.

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def join(ctx):
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
        await bot.join_voice_channel(channel)
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def leave(ctx):
        server = ctx.message.server
        voice_client = bot.voice_client_int(server)
        await voice_client.disconnect()
```

can someone help me?

Comment: Try this https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#voice-changes

Answer (score 8):

As stated in the migrating page, in the rewrite version, the voice connection is now a method of the `VoiceChannel` model.
The `pass_context` is also deprecated as context is now always passed.

It now would look like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
```

Of course this oversimplified version lacks error handling.

Comment: `await voice_channel.connect()` just hangs for me and nothing happens. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'voice'.